# Is there any way to embed serverside JS into HTML (like PHP)?

Tags: javascript, server-side

Is there some way to embed node.js (i.e. server-side) code into HTML, like `<?php` does for PHP? What I'm aiming for is a pretty looking page, which will still have back-end functionality of whatever kind (say printing stuff from a database).
Thanks.

Comment: you need to use done js

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I went to that page, but it looks a little....intimidating, heh! :) What would some code in "done js" look like?

Answer (score 1):

With node, you can use `<?js` tags

Hope this helps

Comment: good one.... :D

Comment: Er - how do I do that please? Could you give an example? (Google's not turning up anything....)